# script to map networkdrive base on username

Tags: windows, networking, cmd, network-drive

I have a .cmd script I want to map a network drive based on the username of the person running it.  So something like this

```
net use K: \\nas001\users\[My_User_Name]
```

Except replace [My_User_name] with the name of the user running the script.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variable %USERNAME% contains the actual user name, so you could use this, but I wouldn't advice this.

Windows has the concept op 'home drive', to which you can connect using:

```
NET USE K: /HOME
```

I think it's better to use that concept.